# Storing information into a database from an outside source?

Tags: php, mysql

Apologies if the question was not specific enough, I wasn't sure how to word it.

I have a question about a problem I'm working on outside of class/school and need help from someone who knows more than I.

I was wondering what would have to be done if I wanted to take a customers information from a payment service like Paypal or Wufoo or similar and store that information in a database of my own.

For example, customers enroll in a summer camp and fill out a form and make a payment on a site that is not mine, so I have no access to the variables, code etc, but I can see the end results, information filled in and if they paid. Instead of entering information by hand It would be instead inserted into a table on a database.

I've tried searching around but to no success and wonder if you had any suggestions on the matter.

Comment: I think you want a API/SOAP..

Comment: What do you mean by "i can see the end results"?  Is it displayed on the screen, are you getting it from a post, etc?

Comment: @nickles80 When they pay and register the entry is added to a recent entry form on wufoo's website.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pull the data and parse it to a format that your application can use. Once your application can understand it, putting it into that database is pretty simple.

It easiest to do the parsing if the format you receive from the payment processor is something like XML or JSON, but if not it isn't usually too hard to write a text parser. Look into regular expressions for handling that sort of thing.